# Create Sequence in Excel with repeating numbers every nth time

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to create a fairly basic sequence using a formula whereby columns follow the following order:

2,2,2,2,6,6,6,6,10,10,10,10,14,14,14,14 .....

I have tried a series of offsets and if statements but couldnt get it to function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For values in a column, in **A1** enter:

```
=4*(ROUNDUP(ROW()/4,0))-2
```

and copy downward:

[image]

If you have **Excel 365** and want to also make a comma-separated list, then pick another cell and enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,A:A)
```

If you have **Excel 365** and want to make a comma-separated list without using a "helper column", then pick a cell and enter:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,4*(ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(20)/4,0))-2)
```

Comment: thank you, thats awesome, it worked really well

Comment: @Pooman19, if it has helped and has answered your question consider to accept it as such by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.